# How to start mysql-shell in mysql-js JavaScript mode?

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

How can I change the `mysqlsh` shell to `mysql-js` JavaScript mode?

Somehow initially I'm in `mysql-py`, and I cannot switch to `\js`, only to `\sql`. Why?

```
$ mysqlsh root@localhost:33060
Cannot set LC_ALL to locale en_US.UTF-8: No such file or directory
Please provide the password for 'root@localhost:33060': ******
MySQL Shell 8.0.23

Copyright (c) 2016, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.
Creating a session to 'root@localhost:33060'
Fetching schema names for autocompletion... Press ^C to stop.
Your MySQL connection id is 240 (X protocol)
Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.
mysql-py []> \js
Unknown command: '\js'
mysql-py []> \sql
Switching to SQL mode... Commands end with ;
mysql-sql []>
```

Installed from: `apt snap install mysql-shell`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `snap` mysql-shell is compiled without the `js` module...

Installing manually solved it:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/

`sudo dpkg -i mysql-shell_8.0.27-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb`